# How can tfs work item details be exported?

Tags: tfs

I don't seem to be able to export tfs work items along with their details, is there any way to do this without using TFSIntegrationTools? (I cannot install these at my work).

Specifically I want to be able to export the Description portion of the Work Item details:

[image]
e

Comment: Can you be more clear about what export means?

Comment: Sorry Mike, I've updated my question to be clearer

Comment: try this tool (https://tfsworkitemsexporter.codeplex.com/releases/) i created it to help me with same purpose

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all you need is the work item data then I would design a flat query, run it and then open it up in Excel. You can modify which columns are visible. Once open you can save it off or print or form a report in excel or what have you.

Your other options are to query the warehouse in sql server or query in code.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sunder/archive/2010/03/02/reporting-in-team-foundation-server-part-7-excel-reports-from-work-item-queries.aspx

Comment: Thanks Mike, looks therefore like I'll have to figure out how to query the tfs db

Comment: You'll want to query the warehouse, not the collection db itself. Read this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/granth/archive/2010/05/09/tfs2010-how-to-query-work-items-using-sql-on-the-relational-warehouse.aspx I query it all the time and it's not so bad.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but I could not benifit from excel, because I wanted to send the list to someone who doesn't have access to the local TFS. So I created a tool to help with that.

In case this helps any one, here is the link to download release one excutables from codeplex https://tfsworkitemsexporter.codeplex.com/

please also feel free to copy the code and edit as you like